# How long is a year?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How long is a Dwarf Fortress year outside of the simulation? For example, how long will it take a newly born child to mature and become a productive member of the fortress?

Comment: an asside to the precise time period:
It is so long, that you should treat any child born in your fortress as permanent dead-weight. Just ignore them. The workers that grow up in a fortress are utterly outnumbered and out-skilled by migrants. 
There are some *advanced baby utilizing strategies*, such as baby body-armour (recuiting mothers into your army, they can take one more arrow than normal troups), and sock drop training (solving the outskilled)..
Generally I just ignore them

Comment: @Oxinabox Yeah, to quote a friend: "children are parasites". I added that because SE thought my question was too short and I couldn't think of anything else to add at the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### In Dwarf Mode

A day is about 1200 time units or ticks, while a year is 403200 ticks. (There are 336 days in a Dwarven year)

The number of ticks per second is dependant on FPS. At 100FPS (default max) 403200 ticks (a year) elapses in about an hour.
Obviously time does not flow when the simulation is paused.

A Dwarven baby takes 12 years to become an adult, or about 12 hours without any pauses.

### In Adventure Mode

Adventure mode counts time differently to Dwarf Mode.
There are 29030400 ticks per year in Adventure mode, however, because Adventure mode is turn based and the number of ticks elapsed is dependant on what actions take place, there is no easy figure here.

Comment: Just to add: at the age of one year, a "baby" (completely reliant on others to bring it food & drink, can't do anything) becomes a "child" (able to get food and drink for itself, will occasionally do useful things like harvesting, when it feels like it.)